# how to show firebase notification message in Layout

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, layout, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to show the message sent by the firebase database admin using firebase messaging service. Message consists of both text and pictures.
Like this [image: Sample screenshot]
I searched about this a lot but couldn't found any method to do this. All the methods available are only for text messages. Can you please tell me the solution of this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the FirebaseMessagingService the Method onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) has an instance of RemoteMessage.

RemoteMessage has a Notification field.

Notification has an imageUrl field.

This way you can transport an imageUrl.
See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.Notification.html#getImageUrl()

Answer (score 3):

Because you want more than a simple notification,
the best thing to do is send a [data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages)

Then in the app you can work with this content and present to user the way you want.